# Selecting start state of dropdown from the second row of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have a multidimensional array , which has "Region" "Country" "state" columns
I have created dropdowns for all these . now i want to set the intial state of these dropdowns to be the values from the second row.
i am trying to write a javascript function that retrieves the value from the array and set the intial state to that value.
Please find my code to create a control wrapper for "Region" below. I would like to put the javascript function inside this control wrapper.Please suggest

```
     var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control1',
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Region',
        'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': false,

        }
    }

    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the row and column in your DataTable that you want to pull your default values from, then the solution is simple:

```
// data is your DataTable object
// regionColumn is the index of the "Region" column in the DataTable
// defaultRow is the row in the DataTable that you want to pull your default values from
var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control1',
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Region',
        'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': false
        }
    },
    state: {
        selectedValues: [data.getValue(defaultRow, regionColumn)]
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried to put the same code by intializing defaultRow to 2.But, its giving out syntax error at state: { line

Comment: please take a look at the code var defaultRow = 2;
    var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control1',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Region',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false,
     //selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
            }
        }
  state: {
        selectedValues: [data.getValue(defaultRow, regionColumn)]
    }

    });

Comment: Do i have to include anything in the header to be able to use the above code?

Comment: Can you update your post with the full javascript or a link to a jsfiddle?  I'd like to test it to see why it isn't working for you.